# DataService how do you pass LONG

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

how do you pass long type parameter with data services? It passes INT with no problems, but what could be the solution for LONG? I tried the method that I use for strings for joke, doesn't seem to work.

```
public TransactionCartItem GetTransactionCartItemByTransactionNumber(long transactionNumber)
{
    transactionNumber = (int)transactionNumber; // it works if I convert to INT (just for debugging reason I tried)

    var query =
        this.ClientRepositories
            .Context
            .CreateQuery<TransactionCartItem>("GetTransactionCartItemByTransactionNumber")
            .AddQueryOption("transactionNumber", transactionNumber)
            .FirstOrDefault();

    return query;
}
```

Error for LONG usage:

> “Bad Request - Error in query syntax.”

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: “Bad Request - Error in query syntax.” .. problem is that INT works so all repositories are properly initialized etc.. I am using this for a long time, but I never had a chance or requirement to use LONG type over wire.

Comment: did you try using fiddler to see what is being sent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OData needs long (Int64) values in Url to be appended with **L**.

Try this and let us know.

```
public TransactionCartItem GetTransactionCartItemByTransactionNumber(long transactionNumber)
{   
    var query =
        this.ClientRepositories
            .Context
            .CreateQuery<TransactionCartItem>("GetTransactionCartItemByTransactionNumber")
            .AddQueryOption("transactionNumber", transactionNumber + "L")
            .FirstOrDefault();

    return query;
}
```

got the documentation.. the Edm.Int64 seems to need a trailing **L** at the end.
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/#AbstractTypeSystem

Comment: When I issue an OData request in the browser using a url, I know that longs must be appended with 'L', so this should work.